# Demonstrating that water density is at its maximum at 4 degree

Tags: thermodynamics, water, education, density, experimental-technique

I want to demonstrate to the students this fact in class. I checked the density of water as a function of temperature. The variation is minute, on the scale of one in ten thousand, from 0 degree to 4 degree.

This might mean this is a bit challenging.

So, does anyone have a good suggestion or any experience?

Comment: Do you have a very very thin pipette? Then the change in density would manifest as a possibly-macroscopic change in water height.

Comment: The setup would be similar to a thermometer - and also serves to demonstrate that a water thermometer is not very good in this range.

Comment: @probably_someone The problem with any such approach is that you have to know (or assume) that the expansion coefficient of whatever container you use is sufficiently small.  (Of course, if you assume that the latter does not have a minimum around 4 C, this could still be used to see that there is a minimum in the density of water somewhere.)

Comment: Ah, yeah, true. Fortunately for us, Pyrex has one of the lowest thermal expansion coefficients, clocking in at 4e-6: http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/linear-expansion-coefficients-d_95.html
I think that was part of its design philosophy.

Comment: @probably_someone My point is more along the lines: If we need to "believe" sth. about thermal expansion coefficients of some material, why don't we right away believe what is written in books about water?  ;-)

Comment: If we keep following that reasoning, why don't we disregard all of the assumptions in every other answer, too? We got them from books, after all.

Comment: @probably_someone That's not my point.  The real question is: How can we measure things like thermal expansion coefficients in the first place? We need a way to find a reference, i.e., at some point we have to measure an exansion coefficient by **other** means than comparing it to another reference material.  (We could, e.g., use an interferometer, so there *are* possiblities!)  I think this is a problem of fundamental importance for metrology.

Comment: @probably_someone (Note on the side: If you want me to be notified about your comments, you have to use @[username].)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Yes, from a metrological standpoint, this is correct. However, considering this is for a class demonstration, minute corrections from the tiny thermal expansion of Pyrex can be neglected, and can be briefly mentioned if asked about by a particularly precocious student. So the above method should be a fine demonstration of the effect. In addition, it is far easier to obtain a pipette than to build an interferometer, which is why I suggested it in the first place.

Comment: @probably_someone I'm not criticizing the pipette idea! (In fact, it was also the first which came to my mind ;-).  The problem of basically just comparing different expansion coefficients is probably common to all classroom approaches.  I just think it would be very neat if there were a way to measure the expansion coefficient without needing to resort to other expansion coefficients.  And that issue should be pointed out to the students upfront.  (Otherwise, you can just as well properly cheat the students.)  BTW, it's not that hard to build simple interferometers.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Speaking from experience, making sure that interferometers actually work properly in a demonstration setting is virtually impossible. They're very easily upset through disturbances and vibrations, which there tend to be a lot of outside labs ;)

Comment: @probably_someone Well, at least then you can blame it on the students ;-)  Anyway, my points were not the interferometers, but that there *are* ways to measure things as expansion coefficients without comparing them to other expansion coefficients.

Comment: Here is such a demonstration https://www.ld-didactic.de/literatur/hb/e/p2/p2131_e.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the following will work, but you may use the fact that water compressibility is very low, so a small water density change due to a temperature change in a fixed volume may cause a significant pressure change, which can be measured.

Comment: For this, you would need to know sth. about the compressibility of water. And you would need a very rigid container.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch : You may need to know the compressibility of water for the purpose of planning the experiment. No knowledge of compressibility is necessary for the actual demonstration: you can just demonstrate that the pressure is at maximum at 4 deg. C. As for a very rigid container... The compressibility of water is 70 times higher than that of steel.

Comment: Well, unless the compressibility also has an anomaly at 4C. ;-)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch : I don't think it's about an anomaly, all you need is low thermal expansion coefficient. I think steel is OK, otherwise invar may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a setup similar to a [Galileo thermometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_thermometer), i.e., have a body with an (average) density which is below the density of water at $4^\circ\mathrm{C}$ but above that at e.g. $0^\circ\mathrm{C}$ and $8^\circ\mathrm{C}$: It would swim at $4^\circ\mathrm{C}$ and sink at both higher and lower temperatures.  This actually works, as witnessed by the Galileo thermometer; if you use a design for your floating body similar to the Galilean thermometer, it should be possible to tune the average density quite precisely.

It seems that the density difference between $0^\circ\mathrm{C}$ and $4^\circ\mathrm{C}$ is about $1/3$ of that between $20^\circ\mathrm{C}$ and $21^\circ\mathrm{C}$, so it should be possible to resolve this difference.  ([Source.](https://www.simetric.co.uk/si_water.htm))

Of course, the same caveat as in my comment above holds: You need to assume that the thermal expansion coefficient of whatever body use use is negligible as compared to that of water.